# Why would a question about HPS lighting be off topic in Electrical Engineering

Tags: discussion, migration

Refer to below question which was moved to DIY by moderators.

https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/121780/hps-bulbs-and-ballast-wattage-compatibilty-vs-replacement-technologies?newreg=7de533eba233467893e63d03a7c92d5a

Electrical Engineering goes much beyond 24V and electronics. Lighting & power are a big and integral part of Electrical Engineering! In fact, the tags "HID" is already existing in electronics.stackexchange.com

And here are a number of similar posts accross electronics.stackexchange.com:

[Powering HID lamp from 240 volts](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/281781/powering-hid-lamp-from-240-volts)

[How do you dim a streetlight bulb?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/24978/how-do-you-dim-a-streetlight-bulb/24992?s=18|0.0977#24992)

[Two bulbs of different wattage in one AC circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/231586/two-bulbs-of-different-wattage-in-one-ac-circuit/231610?s=21|0.0848#231610)

I took care for the original question to cover the broad scope of electrical engineering as the same question/answers would be relevant to others (although in the end I was looking for that answer for a "home improvement". Still, beeing myself an Electrical P.Eng. In my professional work, I have been dealing in a few cases of HPS lighting where I did not find answers to the same questions and would have like to stumble on the answer to the actual post.

I don't think that only for the fact that the actual end-application for the answer is indeed a DIY that the actual question must be posted in DIY. The material and content itself should be the relevant deciding factor to post and keep the question/answer.

Comment: The tag description for HID reads "Human Interface Device, most commonly referring to a USB device, but can also refer to Bluetooth HID devices."  Is this what you mean?  If you can see a difference, that might steer you toward a different stack.

Answer (score 4):

### Do you want an EE or an electrician to answer your question?

While we get some cross-pollination -- when it comes to mains electricity, EE's generally are familiar with the *design* issues, either for mains-powered devices or for high power (industrial and/or MV) work, whereas if you're dealing with lightbulbs/fixtures or general mains wiring standards and practices, an *electrician* is going to know more about that.  In other words: since an EE typically isn't involved when a house or small commercial building is wired, then it's better to ask about topics that have to do with general light-duty building wiring on Home Improvement where you have a better chance of having an electrician answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Before posting, it is customary to check and see if the question will be [on topic.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Quote:

> What topics can I ask about here?
>
> This site is for electronics and electrical engineering professionals,
>   students, and enthusiasts. We ask and answer questions about
>   electrical and electronics engineering topics, which include
>   electronics, physical computing, and those working with
>   microcontrollers, Arduinos and embedded systems. We feel the best
>   Electronics Design questions have a schematic, links to pertinent
>   datasheets or some source code in them, but if your question generally
>   covers …
>
> ```
> a specific electronics design problem
> the theory and simulation of electromagnetic forces
> a communication scheme
> the writing of firmware for bare-metal or RTOS applications
> ```
>
> and it is not about …
>
> ```
> a shopping or buying recommendation
> consumer electronics such as media players, 
> cell phones or smart phones, except when designing these products or  
> modifying their electronics for other uses
> Programming software for a PC
> ```
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

The question you posted falls in a grey area, its not a *design* question which is what most of the moderators here use as a rule of thumb.

The other questions you posted are more design oriented (in general).

The second area that I see a problem with the question you posted, its too broad as you asked several questions. Try and keep questions specific.

If your goal is to get your question answered, you got it answered, and all is well.

The community here is more focused on circuit design, and some power designers not too many commercial electrical or manufacturing engineers, so keep that in mind when writing questions.

Lastly, check the help center for more tips on writing questions.

Comment: Actually, it was answered very well I must say at EE, before beeing moved to DIY. Also, in my experience electricians may now from experience what to do, but often not the underlying reasons for it. The question was really about explaining the underlying principles of design which would then be used to understand the expected result. I think that is indeed more in line with EE crowd than DIY crowd...